# Is there a way to replace a character or string in all fields without writing it for each field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, replace, field

I will warn you up front, this question borders on silly, but I'm asking anyway.

The impetus for my question is creating a csv from a query result and some of the fields containing commas already. Obviously, the csv doesn't know any better and just merrily jacks up my good mood by having some stragglers in non-field columns.

I know I can write

`Replace(FieldName, OldChar, NewChar)`

for each field, but I'm more curious than anything if there's a shortcut to replace them all in the query output.

Basically what I'm looking for (**logically**) is:

```
Replace(AllFields, OldChar, NewChar)
```

I don't know all of the SQL tricks (or many of them), so I thought maybe the SO community may be able to enlighten me...or call me nuts.

Comment: Have you considered using a different field separator for the "csv" file?  For instance, if you used pipe (|), then it probably wouldn't interfere with any fields.  Most applications that import data let you choose the field separator.

Comment: @GordonLinoff cuz that would be too easy and make total sense. =) Like I said, this was more to satisfy my curiosity than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SQL syntax to do what you describe, but as you've seen there are many ways to do this with dynamic SQL. Here's the way I prefer (this assumes you want to replace commas with pipe, change this as you see fit):

```
DECLARE @table   NVARCHAR(511),
        @newchar NCHAR(1),
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @table    = N'dbo.table_name',
       @newchar  = N'|', -- tailor accordingly
       @sql      = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + ',
  ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
    + ' = REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '),'','',''' 
    + @newchar + ''')'
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table)
  ORDER BY column_id;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '')  + ' 
 FROM ' + @table;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.  I often have one-time type cleansing steps in ETL routines.  I find a script like this helps when you need to remove some oddity from an import (rogue page breaks, whitespace, etc.):

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(100) = 'dbo.YourTable';

declare @col nvarchar(max);

-- remove quotes and trim every column, kill page breaks, etc.
;with c_Col (colName)
as  (   select  c.name
        from    sys.tables t 
        join    sys.columns c on
                c.object_id = t.object_id
        where   t.object_id = object_id(@tableName)
    )
select @col = stuff(a.n, 1, 1, '')      
    from    (   select  top 100 percent
                        ',' + c.colName + '= nullif(replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim('+c.colName+ ')), ''"'', ''''), char(13), ''''), char(10), ''''), '''') '
                from    c_col c
                for xml path('')
            ) as a(n)

declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = 'update ' + @tableName + ' set ' + @col

print @cmd;
--exec(@cmd);
```

Comment: Won't `FOR XML PATH` change any legitimate `>`, `<` etc. into `&gt;` and `&lt;`? Also if you bother to include the schema, why ignore it in the comparison instead of saying `t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)`?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment on XML, thinking in too many layers. But it seems odd to go out of your way to avoid comparing the schema along with the table name.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, the script was yanked out of a larger script and I was just using it to illustrate how to build an _update all column_ script for dbo.YourTable.  I'll update the post, thanks for keeping me honest :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to save yourself some typing for a one time query statement affecting all fields in a table then this is a trick I've used in the past.

First query the schema to produce a result set that returns all the field names in any table you specify.  You can modify what I've provided here as a template but I've given the basic structure of an update statement around the field names.

```
select column_name + ' = Replace(' + column_name + ',OldChar,NewChar),' 
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_name = 'YourTableName'
```

The result set comes back in query analyzer as a series of rows that you can highlight (by clicking on column name) and then copying and pasting right back into your query analyzer window.  From there add your update statement to the beginning and where clause to the end.  *You'll also need to get rid of the one extra comma.*

You can then re-run the query to produce the desire outcome.